# Независимо от того(,) что

Tags: запятые

Грамота говорит, что *незивисимо от того, что* надо разделять, ставля две запятые (либо ставля одну – только перед *того*), но я этому не верю. Как правильно?

1. Я, незивисимо от того, что мой папа говорит, стираю моё бельё.
2. Я, незивисимо от того что мой папа говорит, стираю моё бельё.

Comment: конечно нужна зпт

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно:

*Я, **независимо от того что мой папа говорит**, стираю моё бельё.*

Придаточное предложение находится **в середине главного**, поэтому составной союз не расчленяется запятой.

Comment: Без вопросов. Плюсую ваш ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, все по правилам грамматики, не иначе.